# theta series of neighbours

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there a simple relation between the theta series of lattices that are neighbors in the sense of Kneser? In many articles (Nebe, Andrianov etc) there is a connection claimed with the
Hecke operator but this is never clear enough and always in high degree ( I modestly would like to see such a relation in degree (aka genus) ONE.

Comment: welcome to mathoverflow :)

Comment: Even simpler question: can you say when two neighbors have the same number of roots?